# Why are these conflicts appearing in the following yacc grammar for XML

Tags: c, xml, grammar, bison, yacc

I have the following XML grammar which works fine:

```
program 
    : '<' '?'ID attribute_list '?''>' 
      root
    ;
root
    : '<' ID attribute_list '>' node_list '<''/'ID'>'
    ;

node_list
    : node_s
    | node_list node_s
    ;
node_s
    : node
    | u_node
    | ID
    ;

node
    : '<' ID attribute_list '/''>'
    ;
u_node
    :'<' ID attribute_list '>' node_list '<''/'ID'>'
    |'<' ID attribute_list '>' '<''/'ID'>'
    ;

attribute_list
    : attributes
    |
    ;
attributes
    : attribute
    | attributes attribute   
    ;

attribute
    : ID ASSIGNOP '"' ID '"'
    | ID ASSIGNOP '"' NUM '"'
    | ID ASSIGNOP '"' NUM ID'"'
    | ID ASSIGNOP '"' WEB '"'
    ;
```

I don't like the additional statement for empty node_list so I added an empty rule to node_s
    |

but by doing so i get the following conflicts

```
conflicts: 8 shift/reduce
prog1.y:40.10: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts: node_s: /* empty */
```

I have no idea why, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `bison --verbose a.y` prints information into file `a.output`. The file contains information such as:

```
State 27 conflicts: 2 shift/reduce

Grammar

    3 node_list: node_s
    4          | node_list node_s

    5 node_s: node
    6       | u_node
    7       | ID
    8       | /* empty */

...

state 27

    2 root: '<' ID attribute_list '>' . node_list '<' '/' ID '>'

    ID   shift, and go to state 28
    '<'  shift, and go to state 29

    ID   [reduce using rule 8 (node_s)]
    '<'  [reduce using rule 8 (node_s)]

    node_list  go to state 30
    node_s     go to state 31
    node       go to state 32
    u_node     go to state 33

state 28

    7 node_s: ID .
```

Here we can see that in state 27 there are 2 shift/reduce conflicts. I will describe the 1st shift/reduce conflict: when the state machine is in state 27, and the input is `ID`, the machine can do two actions:

```
shift, and go to state 28
[reduce using rule 8 (node_s)]
```

The 1st action was generated by rule 7 `node_s:ID`, the 2nd action was generated by rule 8 `node_s:/*empty*/`. It is ambiguous which action to choose.

`node_list` is list of `node_s`. In state 27, the input `ID` can be parsed as

```
<nothing> ID     node_list = node_s:/*empty*/, node_s:ID
```

or as

```
ID               node_list = node_s:ID
```

In other words, it is impossible to decide whether the node list should begin with an empty node.

To fix this problem, the grammar should be modified like this:

```
node_list
    : /*empty*/
    | node_list node_s
    ;
node_s
    : node
    | u_node
    | ID
    ;

u_node
    :'<' ID attribute_list '>' node_list '<''/'ID'>'
    ;
```

Now, when parsing `node_list '<''/'ID'>'`, **the input will unambiguously determine** whether the node list is empty or non-empty:

```
INPUT   ACTION
< /     empty node list
< ID    non-empty node list
ID      non-empty node list
```

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, I didn't know about `--verbose a.y` this will be useful in the future.